# What is wrong with this proof that $p_1 > \omega(x)$, where $p_1$ is the least prime dividing $x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, proof-verification, divisor-sum

Let $x \in \mathbb{N}$, and let 
$$x = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(x)}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}$$
be the *canonical factorization* of $x$.  (That is, the $p_i$'s are primes with
$p_1 < \ldots < p_{\omega(x)}$.)  Note that $\omega(x)$ is the number of *distinct* prime factors of $x$.

> What is wrong with this proof that $p_1 > \omega(x)$, where $p_1$ is the least prime dividing $x$?

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of the divisors of $x$.  Then the *abundancy index* $I(x) = \sigma(x)/x$ is bounded above by
$$I(x) = I\left(\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(x)}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}\right) = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(x)}{I\left({p_i}^{\alpha_i}\right)} < \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(x)}{\left(\frac{p_i}{p_i - 1}\right)}.$$

Now, I use the inequality
$$\frac{p_i}{p_i - 1} < \frac{p_1 - (i - 1)}{p_1 - i}$$
for $i \neq 1$.  This yields
$$1 \leq I(x) < \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(x)}{\left(\frac{p_i}{p_i - 1}\right)} = \left(\frac{p_1}{p_1 - 1}\right)\prod_{i=2}^{\omega(x)}{\left(\frac{p_i}{p_i - 1}\right)} < \left(\frac{p_1}{p_1 - 1}\right)\prod_{i=2}^{\omega(x)}{\left(\frac{p_1 - (i - 1)}{p_1 - i}\right)} = \frac{p_1}{p_1 - \omega(x)}.$$

Finally, I have $p_1 > \omega(x)$.

Comment: Take $x=30..........$

Comment: It may happen that some $i$ is equal to $p_1$.

Comment: i=2p1  (p_i)(p_i - 1) > (p_1 - 1)/p_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the claimed inequality

$$\frac{p_i}{p_i-1}<\frac{p_1-(i-1)}{p_1-i}\;.\tag{1}$$

Take, for example, $x=2\cdot3\cdot5$ and $i=3$: $(1)$ claims that $\frac54<\frac0{-1}=0$, which is absurd. (And taking $i=2$ is in some ways even more of a problem!)