# Requesting for details of Grun's result on odd perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, reference-request, perfect-numbers

This post is an offshoot of this [earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687890).

According to this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3APerfect_number#Perisastri_and_Grun):

> Grun $1952$ proved that the smallest prime factor $p_1$ (of an odd perfect number $N$) is $< \frac{2\omega(N)}{3} + 2$ (where $\omega(N)$ is the number of *distinct* prime factors of $N$), and Perisastri $1958$ published the same result.

My question is:  Does anybody here know the details of this result of Grun's?  I mean, would you be able to reproduce Grun's proof here?

Thanks!

Comment: Otto Grun, Uber ungerade vollkommene Zahlen , Math. Zietschr. 55 (1952) is the name of the paper, I think..